# saving columns in an other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

i have this code , normally it saves a sheet with the possibility of giving it a new name , i tried to change it to save just some columns and not the hole sheet but the code showes me eror 1004 , can any one help me with this please thank you 
this is my code :

```
Sub save()
Worksheets("operations").Activate
Dim sName As String
     Sheets("operations").Range("N1:Q6000").Copy Destination:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
   On Error Resume Next
   Do
      sName = InputBox("Enter name for the release")
      If sName = "" Then
         Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         ActiveSheet.Delete
         Exit Sub
      End If
      ActiveSheet.Name = sName
      If ActiveSheet.Name = sName Then Exit Do
      Beep
   Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub save()
    Dim sName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    sName = InputBox("Enter name for the release")

    If Not sName = "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = Sheets(sName)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If ws Is Nothing Then
            Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            Sheets("operations").Range("N1:Q6000").Copy Destination:=Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1")
            ActiveSheet.Name = sName
        Else
            Beep
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Couple of things...

1. Ask for the name first.
2. Do not use a Do Loop
3. Check if the name given by the user doesn't match with the existing sheet
4. When specifying a destination, specify the range as well. I have used `A1` as an example.